# NoReverseMatch where trying pass javascript varaible to url tag

Tags: django

My urls look like:

```
url(r'^box_detail/', BoxJson.as_view(), name='box_details'),
url(
    r'^box_detail/(?P<box_id>\d+)/',
    BOXJson.as_view(), name='box_details'
)
```

and in js when i'm trying this:

```
var id = 5;
"{% url 'box_details' id %}"
```

I get

```
Reverse for 'box_details' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['api/box_detail/(?P<box_id>\\d+)/', 'api/box_detail/']
```

I must use this:

```
"{% url 'box_details' %}" + id
```

but this looks not good, is there any option to do this?
Django 1.10.3

Comment: Why do you have two urls with same name?Change the name of second url.

Comment: And also try with [0-9]+ instead of \d because the error line is showing two \\d.